# FastAPI is not loading static files

Tags: javascript, python, fastapi, static-files, starlette

So, I'm swapping my project from node.js to python FastAPI. Everything has been working fine with node, but here it says that my static files are not present, so here's the code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="../static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='../templates')

@app.get('/')
async def index_loader(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {"request": request})
```

The project's structure looks like this: 
[image: Project structure]

Files are clearly where they should be, but when I connect to the website, the following error occurs:

```
←[32mINFO←[0m:     connection closed
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54295 - "←[1mGET /img/separator.png HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54296 - "←[1mGET /css/rajdhani.css HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54295 - "←[1mGET /js/pixi.min.js HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54296 - "←[1mGET /js/ease.js HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54298 - "←[1mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[32m200 OK←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54298 - "←[1mGET /img/separator.png HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54299 - "←[1mGET /css/rajdhani.css HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54298 - "←[1mGET /js/pixi.min.js HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54299 - "←[1mGET /js/ease.js HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m
```

So, basically, any static file that I'm using is missing, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="../static"), name="static")
```

You mount your static directory under `/static` path. That means, if you want access static files in your html you need to use `static` prefix, e.g. `<img src="static/img/separator.png"/>`

Answer (score 1):

#### Mounting a `StaticFiles` instance

To mount a [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/#use-staticfiles) instance to a specific path, you could use the following example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

#### Provide links to `StaticFiles` in Jinja2 template

Linking to `static` files in your Jinja2 template could be achieved in the following way, as described in [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/templates/):

```html
<link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/css/rajdhani.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Alternatively**, you could directly use the pathname given when you mounted a [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/#use-staticfiles) instance. In this case, that is, `/static`. Hence, [any path that starts with `/static` will be handled by the `StaticFiles` "sub-application"](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/#details):

```html
<link href="static/css/rajdhani.css'" rel="stylesheet">
```

For more details, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911598/17865804).

Answer (score 0):

```
folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=folder+"/../static",html=True), name="static")
```

works. Somehow using `directory="../static"` does not work, the full path is required when pointing outside of your FastAPI project. Then `html=True` is also needed for serving html files correctly. See https://www.starlette.io/staticfiles/.