# How to set the initial directory for front-end

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app. The structure of the app is something like this:

```
app
.... main.py
.... client
........ index.html
........ index.js
........ style.css
........ cfg
............ index.html
............ index.js
............ style.css
........ components
............ libs
................. etc
```

File main.py

```py
app = FastAPI()

app.mount('/client', StaticFiles(directory='client'), name='static')

@app.get('/')
async def get():
    return FileResponse('client/index.html')

@app.get('/cfg')
async def cfg():
    return FileResponse('client/cfg/index.html')
```

File client/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="libs/d3/d3.v7.js"></script>

    <script src="libs/billboard/billboard.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/billboard/billboard.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/billboard/datalab.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/datePicker/air-datepicker.css">

    <script src="./index.js" type="module" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<dash-board></dash-board>

</body>
</html>
```

File client/cfg/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="./index.js" type="module" defer></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../libs/codemirror-5.65.13/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../libs/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/hint/show-hint.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../libs/codemirror-5.65.13/theme/idea.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/jsonTree/jsonTree.css">
    <script src="../libs/jsonTree/jsonTree.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<cfg-main></cfg-main>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch the application and go to the path localhost:8000, GET requests with the paths specified in the HTML files come to the server.
For example: "GET /index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found. Accordingly, I get an error that such a file was not found, because the root directory "client" is not specified at the beginning.
How do I make the root directory specified? Paths cannot be adjusted in the HTML file.

I tried using redirection:

```py
@app.get('/')
async def get():
    return RedirectResponse('client/index.html')
```

In this case, everything loads and works fine. GET requests are received indicating the root directory. But then the URL changes to localhost:8000/client/index.html. This method is not suitable.

I tried to do this:

```py
app.mount('/', StaticFiles(directory='client'), name='static')
```

It doesn't work in my case. The main problem is that I have a cfg folder in my client folder. When opening a file cfg/index.html , the server receives requests for files "index.js" and "style.css" by the paths "index.js" and "index.css". There are these files on the server, but they are not the same files. I need files from the cfg folder. That is, the paths must be cfg/index.js and cfg/style.css.

Comment: If you want to access the other files under the root path (e.g. localhost:800]/index.js), you have to mount your `StaticFiles` on `"/"`, not `"/client"`. Also, you can use `html=True` in `StaticFiles` to automatically serve `index.js` when navigating to a directory.

Comment: Related answers to the link provided above can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528465/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636404/17865804)