# Why are the css files not connecting to the jinja2 template in Fastapi?

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

everybody!
I have the following application structure in Fastapi:

```
-app
-templates
-static
```

All directories are on the same level. In the app directory I have a main.py file with this code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="../static"), name='static')

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="../templates")

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

In the file index.html I connect

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', path='css/style.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', path='/css/styles_carousel.css') }}">
```

The html template itself is loaded, but the css files are not visible.
I tried changing the structure to this:

```
-app
-main.py
--templates
--static
```

And it still turns out the same
Can you please tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you looked at what the path generated by the `url_for` call is? And what happens when you open that URL manually?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911598/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636404/17865804) helpful.