# How to download file from flet-fastapi server to client?

Tags: python, http, fastapi, uvicorn, flet

I have a flеt website that runs on flеt-fastapi and uviсorn. How can I download a file located on the server to the client device?

For example, the code of a small application:

```
import flet as ft
import flet_fastapi


async def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "TestApp"
    await page.add_async(ft.Text("this is test app"))


app = flet_fastapi.app(main, upload_dir="files", secret_key="secret_key")
app.mount(path="/files", app=flet_fastapi.FletStaticFiles())
```

I expect that when accessing the link "http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/IMG.jpg" the file ./files/IMG.jpg will be downloaded to the client device. In fact, this link is accessible to the same website as the link "http://127.0.0.1:8000", although the server reports

> INFO: 127.0.0.1:64179 - "GET /files/IMG.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Comment: Please have a look at the following answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636404/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911598/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804). Further related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804)

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the answer. I read what you advised, and saw the "Starlette FileResponse" solution that seems to work, but I'm not sure how to use something like that in my application. I used flet-fastapi as stated in [docs](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/deploying-web-app/running-flet-with-fastapi) and I'm not sure how it should work together.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for your advice, I edited the original post and tried to give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Chris The problem is that the browser opens the main page of the site instead.

Comment: @Chris something like this, the address bar displays "http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/IMG.jpg", but the response is the same as from "http://127.0.0.1:8000", although the server continues write "INFO: 192.168.0.11:56744 - "GET /files/IMG.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 OK" with each request

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I already tried this, including connecting to the site from other devices.
Regarding the second question, in the example from the original post, a one-page site is created with the text “this is test app”, the link “http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/IMG.jpg” leads to it, although it should lead to an image

Comment: Please note that, in FastAPI, the order in which you define the endpoints **matters**. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804)