# FastAPI is unable to fetch static files

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I'm learning FastAPI and seem to have hit a roadblock.
This is the structure of my project:

```
apitest
    -main.py
    -index.html
    -style.css
    -script.js
```

Following are the contents of main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return FileResponse('index.html')
```

This is the skeleton of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test123</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the server `uvicorn main:app --reload`, the webpage contains only static text i.e. the css is not loaded and the console gives me the errors:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51474 - "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51476 - "GET /script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

In my browser (firefox) if I go to the debug console, it shows the following errors:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/script.js”. 127.0.0.1:8000:104:119
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Source Map URL: normalize.min.css.map
```

Any idea why I am facing this issue?
I tried to serve the css via staticfiles but that gave me the same errors.

```
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

Comment: In addition to the link above, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636404/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911598/17865804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt doesn't work because it only knows how to fetch the url `/`:

```
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return FileResponse('index.html')
```

When a request comes in for `style.css` or `script.js`, it doesn't match any routes in your application.

Your second attempt doesn't work because you don't have a directory named `static`, and your `index.html` doesn't refer to files in `static`. If you have this:

```
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

Then you need to:

1. Create a directory `static` and move both `script.js` and `style.css` into this directory.
2. Modify `index.html` to load `/static/script.js` and `/static/style.css`:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" >
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Test123</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   .
   .
   .
   </script><script  src="/static/script.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

With these changes, the resources are loaded as expected.

---

> My mistake I should've mentioned that I did create a static directory and placed script.js & style.css in it. I still faced the same issue.

Mounting the `StaticFiles` handler on `/static` works just fine.

Given this code in `main.py`:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return FileResponse('index.html')
```

And this directory layout:

```
.
├── index.html
├── main.py
└── static
    ├── script.js
    └── style.css
```

And this content in the static files:

```
echo This is style.css > static/style.css
echo This is script.js > static/script.js
```

If I run:

```
uvicorn main:app
```

Then I can successfully request those static files:

```
$ curl -s localhost:8000/static/script.js
this is scripts.js
$ curl -s localhost:8000/static/style.css
this is style.css
```

If that's not working for you, odds are you're doing something different than what I've shown in this answer.

You can see a demo of this working [here](https://asciinema.org/a/LIoQaZNzbNeleYjiCSMrb5mHm).

> So for the first attempt - should I create routes for style.css and script.js? For the second attempt

I wouldn't; that will just end up adding a bunch of unnecessary routes every time you have more static content. Using the `StaticFiles` method makes the most sense.

Comment: So for the first attempt - should I create routes for style.css and script.js?

For the second attempt - My mistake I should've mentioned that I did create a static directory and placed script.js & style.css in it. I still faced the same issue.

Comment: I've updated the answer in response to your comment.